# Double items in a heap insert method

Tags: java

I am seeing a strange behavior from adding item to a binary heap. I add three values: `20,31,12`. When I check the items in the array there are now 5 values: `12,20,20,31,12`. I can't figure out where the duplicates come from. Why is it duplicating items?

Adding the item:

```
public void add(int x){     
    int hole = heap.size();
    heap.add(hole, x);
    bubbleUp(hole);     
}
```

The `bubbleup` method:

```
private void bubbleUp(int child) {
    int parent;
    Bid tmp;

    if (child != 0) {
        parent = (child-1)/2;
        if (heap.get(parent).compareTo(heap.get(child))) {
            tmp = heap.get(parent);
            heap.add(parent, heap.get(child));
            heap.add(child, tmp);                           
            bubbleUp(parent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add(int,Object)` is most likely *inserting*. Try `set(int,Object)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I feel ashamed...i should have spotted this error. Well i wont do it again! ;) Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

It's here

```
heap.add(parent, heap.get(child));
heap.add(child, tmp);
```

What you want to do is to exchange the elements. The [two argument version of `add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) still adds one element, instead of replacing the previous value at the position.

Use [`set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29) instead.

Comment: I bow my head to your Kung-Fu, and bang my head in the desk! Thanks a million!! I knew it was something simple...it's usually those small things that really hides well. Thanks again!